# Caching time series aggregates of diffs

Tags: algorithm, caching, language-agnostic, aggregate

Is it possible to precalculate (cache) aggregates (min/max/avg) of values which are a **difference of two signals**?

I have several channels (e.g. 50), with one or more measurements each second, and I can easily store precalculated 1-minute or 15-minute aggregates for faster display.

But one of the requirements is to show a chart of relative values. E.g. if I have channels `C1`, `C2` and `C3`, user would like to see averages of `C1`, and averages of `(C2 - C3)` (or 15-minute minimum/maximum) on a separate chart.

For examples, let's say I have these 2 channels (and 48 more):

```
t(min)    0    +1   +2   +3   +4   +5   +6   +7   +8   +9   +10
C1       0.0  0.1  0.2 -0.1  0.0  0.1  0.3  0.5  0.7  0.9  0.2
C2       0.1  0.4  0.2  0.1 -0.1  0.5  0.6  0.1  0.2  0.3  0.0
```

I can precalculate and store 5-minute aggregates:

```
t(min)    0 to +4    +5 to +10
C1_min     -0.1         0.1
C1_max      0.2         0.9
C2_min     -0.1         0.0
C2_max      0.4         0.6
```

And easily get 10-min or 15-min aggregates from this.

But if user want's to see `min(C2-C1)` or `max(C2-C1)` 5-minute aggregates, for any combination of these 50 channels, it seems that I cannot reuse this information.

In other words, it seems to me that it's impossible to precalculate this, apart from storing each possible combination of these tuples, because `min(C2-C3)` doesn't equal `min(C2)-min(C3)`.

Am I missing some idea which might help me calculate these values faster?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I updated the question, I hope this makes it slightly clearer.

Comment: I think you're right about min and max (consider two identical signals..  their difference will be zero).  the average is okay though, ave(A-B) = ave(A)-ave(B)  (see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360311/why-is-the-average-of-a-sum-equal-the-sum-of-the-averages)

Comment: @danh: I didn't realize this about average until now, but it makes perfect sense, thanks for the helpful link! I am still unsure if anything at all can be done to speed up `min(A-B)` aggregates (i.e. to avoid going through the entire database each time). The example in my question is simplified, but there are actually many measurements per second, and the "minimum of differences" requirement really screwed up my hopes about fast charting.

Comment: ~1Hz for 15min is only 900 samples, couldn't you compute the diff on demand  (keep a running min and max as you take the diff) quickly enough for a user to see it as real time?

Comment: I have 10Hz (sometimes up to 50Hz), but user often requests a week or two of data. They also often want to see multiple channels at once (e.g. `min(B-A)`, `min(C-A)`, `min(D-A)`, and `A` can be any channel), so it adds up quickly. For 10Hz, precalculating 5-min aggregates reduces the number of points 9000x per channel, so the difference is huge. Or I can get (say) 1h aggregates from 5min aggregates quicky - unless they request a diff.

Comment: Is the data continuous, and do you know something about the max freq. of the thing being sampled?  Then there's a chance to sample more sparsely to compute the diff (Nyqust aliasing, I think, but be advised that I'm outside of my field on this).  Closer to my skill set: have some kitten videos on-hand to show user while you do the long diff.

Comment: The signal can be of any kind, it isn't a sinusoidal function, so skipping samples can easily result in min/max sample being missed. Good idea for the distraction videos, however. :)

Comment: If something approximate would be good enough, you can get an *upper bound* on max(A-B) using max(A)-min(B), and a lower bound using min(A)-max(B).  If these turn out to be equal, you have the answer!  (Unlikely though -- that means that neither A nor B changed at all during that time interval.)  If the upper and lower bound are at least close to one another, you know the answer with some "precision".

Answer (score 1):

You would simply need to have all the data of `C2` and `C3` to get the aggregation `min(C2-C3)`.

However, if your goal is to minimize the data required to do this calculation, I suggest you do it in the following way (this solution will require dealing with big numbers - depending on the number of channels):

If you know all channels will not have values that exceeds a certain value (let's say it's `10`) then we can combine all the channels' data in 1 channel, let's name it `C`

To calculate `C`:

```
C = (C1 * 10^1) + (C2 * 10^2) + (C3 * 10^3) + .. + (Cn * 10^n).
```

You would end up having a channel `C` that has all the channels values embedded.

Then to calculate the difference between 2 channels at some point, all you have to do is to "extract" those 2 channels values from `C` on the fly:

```
C1 = floor((C mod 10^1) / 10^(1-p)) / 10^p
C2 = floor((C mod 10^2) / 10^(2-p)) / 10^p
...
Cn = floor((C mod 10^n) / 10^(n-p)) / 10^p
```

Where `p` is the decimal precision of the extracted channel value.

In this case calculation of diff between two channels `x` and `y` using pre-calculated `C` would be:

```
min(Cy-Cx) = min((floor((C mod 10^y) / 10^(y-p)) / 10^p) - (floor((C mod 10^x) / 10^(x-p)) / 10^p))
```

And then you can aggregate those values over intervals of time. Hope it helps.

Comment: But this still means I need to read every single `C`, and each `C` is at least as large as sum of all the channels. Meaning I would have to read even more data this way (well, less table accesses, but larger total amount of data).

Comment: It surely depends on your resource boundaries, in this case `C` would be a large number yes, but you're calculating it only once in the pre-calculation phase along with the mins and maxes.
But then, when you want to generate the diff aggregation, you don't need to access all the channels data of the aggregation period, its only a matter of accessing the `C` values of the corresponding time-slot.

Comment: So for your example: if you have 50 channels, this will save you looping over all the combinations of these channels data, and allow you to get the diffs by just accessing `C` values.
Are you limited by memory size?

Comment: These values are stored inside several database tables. There is no "maximum value" that I can define (and I don't think this simple addition approach would work with negative values). So the only way to place multiple tables into a single one would be to binary concatenate them (i.e. 4 floats would have to be stored into 16 bytes), so total amount of data I would have to read would be the same as reading each table separately.